# Jquery not working in only Chrome & Safari

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

On my website I have a main body that has a height of 100%, the jquery is supposed to find the height of the main body then change the css on the sidebar to match it's height. It works on Firefox and all versions of IE but not in Chrome or Safari. I'm a bit new at this so thanks in advance for your help.
Here's my site: http://avk.io-web.com/product-list/healthy-gormet-cookies
and here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var SecondaryContentHeight= $(".secondary_body_content").height()
$(".left_menu").css("height", SecondaryContentHeight);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `outerHeight(true)` instead of `height()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the height before all of the stuff in the body content is loaded. If you delete the big image in the body content you would see that they mostly line up. Remember the document ready fires when the DOM is ready not when everything in the page has finished loading. You could bind a .load() event to the images on the page that then calculates the height of the left menu but that won't work 100%.

The ideal solution is to do it all in HTML and CSS.  There are a lot of fixed column css layout samples. [one example is here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

By they way, it also doesn't work in FireFox if you clear your cache and scroll down fast enough.  Sometimes the image will load before the javascript but that is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks that really helped! I replaced my $(document).ready() with $(window).load() and it looks like that fixed it!

Comment: you could also consider setting the height (and width) of the image in css, so you don't get that ugly resize when the image finishes loading (perhaps even a preloader as background). Then your document.ready should work again and be a bit faster...

Comment: Great! However notice that it still has to wait a bit for the left bar to grow to size. It's best if you eventually switch to not using javascript for this :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    var SecondaryContentHeight = $(".secondary_body_content").height();
    $(".left_menu").css("height", SecondaryContentHeight);
});
</script>
```

or optimized

```
<script>$(window).load(function(){$(".left_menu").css("height",$(".secondary_body_content").height())})</script>
```

Comment: I cannot see what you've changed in your first sample

Comment: Semicolon after the var statement.

Comment: Semicolons are optional in javascript.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder: in that case it doesn't change anything

Comment: @TheZ I know, but maybe it did the trick, what it doesn't.
Second one is working zerkms?

Comment: @Fleshgrinder Semicolon or not, your script does exactly the same thing the original does. It does not fix anything.

Comment: The DOM is ready, but the page isn't fully loaded and Chrome is executing the jQuery code before the .secondary_body_content is fully rendered. The main problem here is not jQuery nor Chrome, it's the fact that you don't specify image dimensions which is bad. You're welcome.

Comment: BTW I edited my initial answer and the code is now working. So you may want to simply write correct HTML or use my new snippet.

Comment: I replaced my $(document).ready() with $(window).load() and it looks like that fixed it! Thanks everyone!!

Comment: The reason is, that `$(window).load()` will call it's inner anonymous function after ALL resources of the page are loaded and the reflow of the page layout (which is triggered by the image) also finished and then the element from which you want to get the height has the correct height you want. There are other CSS based techniques to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me in chrome on your website:

```
$(".left_menu").height($(".secondary_body_content").height());
```